# Why does a multiplied texture with alpha loose detail information?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

The left image shows the texture mapped to a plane, the right one is original image in the *UV Editor*. The rendered image looks extremely blurred. What would be the correct material and texture settings to have only the alpha part (check pattern right) invisible?

[.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/29932)

[image]

Material and texture settings are:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the left image the rendered output, or in the textured 3D view?

Comment: .blend will help with trouble shooting. I have a feeling that it might be caused by mit mapping. also, how is it unwrapped?

Comment: @David it is the rendered 3D-View.

Comment: @user2926289 I added the .blend, it is a simply a plane unwrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the *Blend Mode* to multiply isn't necessary.

Material Settings:

- Specular

  - Intensity: 0.0

  removes this: [image]
- Transparency: On

  - Method: Z Transparency
  - Alpha Slider 0.0

Texture Settings:

- Type: Image or Movie
- Image: The Texture Image
- Use Alpha: On (Otherwise darker parts of the image which are supposed to be opaque will be partially transparent)
- Image Sampling

  - Alpha: Use : On (Otherwise darker parts of the image which are supposed to be opaque will be partially transparent)                   [image]
- Mapping

  - Coordinates: UV
  - Map: UVMap
- Influence

  - Color: On (1.0)
  - Alpha: On (1.0)
- Blend: Mix (Default)

Settings to compare:

[image]
[image]

Result (left rendered, right image editor)
[Image source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mond#mediaviewer/Datei:Full_Moon_Luc_Viatour.jpg) by Luc Viatour / www.Lucnix.be

[image]

Result zoomed

[image]