# Image plane is blocking the one behind it despite transparency

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency

The images have alpha channel checked on. In normal view the image looks fine but when I render the images cutoff the ones behind it.

[image]

There should be no gap between those 2 images but the one closer to the camera is cutting off the one behind it. I used the import images as planes addon. My goal is to export a png file that is transparent except for the colored areas. I'm gonna import this file into Unity so it needs to have a transparent background.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend or a screenshot of your material settings? I'm guessing that you are using BI and don't have transparency enabled in your material settings (or if you do, then it's set to *mask*). If that is the case, try Z-transparency instead.

Comment: Yes changing it to Z transparency fixed it at least when I go to Render- Render Image. I hope this is how it'll save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enable *Transparency* in the material settings:

[image]

Using [mask transparency](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Properties/Mask_Transparency) won't work because it renders sky where there is transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the basic z-transparency settings from this answer: [Why does a multiplied texture with alpha loose detail information?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13380/why-does-a-multiplied-texture-with-alpha-loose-detail-information)

In the material settings' *Shadow*  tick *Receive Transparency* and disable *Cast*.

The first image shows the same situation as in your post. The transparent parts of the texture cast a shadow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now there is no longer a shadow casted from the transparent part, but might also want to remove the shadow from the opaque image.

[image]
[image]